# UFW Unblock Host to Guest Traffic

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, ufw

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I have enable UFW as a killswitch to work with my wireguard vpn.  My current rules work perfectly, except that traffic between my ubuntu host and my debian 10.5 virtualbox guest is blocked.

How can I unblock host / guest traffic?

My current UFW Rules are:

```
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on wg-client1     (out)
[ 3] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] Anywhere on wg-client1     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 6] 94.121.83.88               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 7] 21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 8] 53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 9] 9418/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

I previously tried the following that all failed (i.e. when I ping guest ip192.168.0.84, I get `ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted`)

```
[10] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    10.10.10.2                
[11] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24            
[12] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24            
[13] 192.168.0.0/24             ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[14] 192.168.0.0/24 22          ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[15] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24 22
```

I also use masquerade to put all traffic through the vpn.  My `ifconfig -a` output is:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.18  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether b4:a9:fc:b0:b0:d1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 668474  bytes 477052588 (477.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 945227  bytes 553827446 (553.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2106  bytes 198789 (198.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2106  bytes 198789 (198.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wg-client1: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.10.10.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.10.10.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 565766  bytes 350115976 (350.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 451704  bytes 440547648 (440.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s10f2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 34:cf:f6:61:c0:38  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 433847  bytes 102427035 (102.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 94319  bytes 29872001 (29.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It should be noted that my debian guest has two network interfaces, 1 static 192.168.0.84 and one dynamic so that I can use multiple wifi networks.

```
# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
        address 192.168.0.84
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
       
#dynamic gateway for Internet access on random networks
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

thx

**UPDATE**
I finally figured out my sys logs and I noticed this:
`[UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp0s10f2 SRC=192.168.0.255 DST=192.168.0.84 ....`

So of course, I checked the vbox manager and for my bridged connection adapters, I only have 2 options: `wlp0s10f2` or `enp3s0` (ethernet)

Even though `ifocnfig -a` shows `wg-client1` as network interface, I don't have `wg-client1` as an available interface in virtualbox.

I played with different rules to allow 22/tcp from `wlp0s10f2` on `wg-client1`, but haven't been successful.

Any tips?

Comment: Is the VirtualBox VM's network connection configured to "Allow All" in the Advanced⇢Promiscuous Mode setting?

Comment: I just verified that my two adapters were/are both set to "Allow All"  and tested with ping..  no luck... still blocked

Comment: @matigo I narrowed down the problem...  any ideas? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little embarrassing, but less than 5 minutes after starting the bounty I solved the problem with an educated guess:

`sudo ufw allow out on wlp0s10f2 from any to 192.168.0.84`

Now my fresh install works perfectly.  My mistake was using the vpn ip as the out to address. Changing that to the ip address of the vbox machine. Got me back on track.